# Why does import work with Python nose when test directory contains __init__.py?

Tags: python, nose

Consider the following project structure:

```
a.py
test/
  test_a.py
```

with `test_a.py` importing module `a`:

```
import a
```

As expected, running `nosetests` in the `test` directory results in import error:

```
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named a)
```

However, I noticed that adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the `test` directory makes import work with `nosetests` (but not when you run `test_a.py` with Python). Could you explain why?

I understand that adding `__init__.py` makes `test` a package. But does it mean that import includes the directory containing the package in the lookup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: @Mir I understand what `__init__.py` for. I don't understand why it affects import of other modules.

Comment: Because if it wasn't in there, then you could import any directory by accident, which would be next to useless. Its a programmatic check of sorts.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper But I'm not importing a package. I'm importing module `a`.

Comment: People need to read OPs question a bit more carefully. Why would making  `test` a package suddenly make `import a` look up `a` in the scope of the *parent* module?

Comment: Its still in a directory though, is it not? If you want to just... import a, it still needs to be in a python package. It can't stand alone. Ah, you're wondering how it finds it in parent directory. Import has a search functionality built in. Im assuming it would start in the parent directory if the file isn't in the current directory.

Comment: No, `a.py` is a file (Python module), not a directory.

Comment: @vitaut the Python version is very relevant here (regarding import mechanics). Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @LukasGraf This is on Python 2.7. This is probably more of a question about Nose than Python, because running `test_a.py` with Python give import error in both cases. Probably some `nosetests` does some magic with the import paths but I couldn't find anything about it in the docs.

Comment: @LukasGraf I don't think the behaviour is different between python 2 and 3 here.

Comment: @vitaut Checked in the source code and found out why. Sorry I didn't read your questions closely the first time.

Comment: @wim I'm not positive it is (or whether this is even a Python issue rather than a side effect of some test discovery magic). But things did change regarding explicit vs. implicit relative imports between 2 and 3, so I just thought it to be helpful to get the question of the Python version out of the way early on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presence of an `__init__.py` file in the directory transforms `test` from just a plain old directory into a python [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). This has an effect on `sys.path`.

Modify your `test_a.py` module like this:

```
import sys

def test_thing():
    for i, p in enumerate(sys.path):
        print i, p

try:
    import a
except ImportError:
    print('caught import error')
```

Then try running `nosetests -s` from the test directory, with and without an `__init__.py` in there.

*Note*: it is the test runner that munges `sys.path`.  And that is documented in [the second "Note" of this section here](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules) (thanks @davidism).  You won't see any change there just by running `python test_a.py` with and without the package structure.

Comment: I understand that, but how does it affect import lookup?

Comment: Right.  I've added more detail.

Comment: Yes, and they explicitly recommend to *not* put the `__init__.py` in the tests directory.  You should set up `PYTHONPATH` in your virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @wim. The first entry in sys.path turned out to be the project directory which explains why import works. I wonder why nosetests puts it there.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the souce code of nose module and here's why.

```
def importFromPath(self, path, fqname):
    """Import a dotted-name package whose tail is at path. In other words,
    given foo.bar and path/to/foo/bar.py, import foo from path/to/foo then
    bar from path/to/foo/bar, returning bar.
    """
    # find the base dir of the package
    path_parts = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(path)).split(os.sep)
    name_parts = fqname.split('.')
    if path_parts[-1] == '__init__.py':
        path_parts.pop()
    path_parts = path_parts[:-(len(name_parts))]
    dir_path = os.sep.join(path_parts)
    # then import fqname starting from that dir
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)

def importFromDir(self, dir, fqname):
    """Import a module *only* from path, ignoring sys.path and
    reloading if the version in sys.modules is not the one we want.
    """
    dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(dir))
```

In your case when importFromDir is called from importFromPath, 'dir' is the directory a level above from the `__init__.py` directory. So that's why adding `__init__.py` to your test makes 'import a' work